# How to make a normal video from time lapse recording?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I did record a video on iPhone using timelapse mode. It was by mistake. It was very important video for me. In timelapse mode it is useless... is there a way to convert recording to normal video? Need to recover picture and voice.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, it is going to be difficult-to-impossible to make a recording look even somewhat "normal" from time-lapsed footage. Normal iPhone video footage is shot at about 30 frame per second, while time-lapsed footage varies between **one and two frame per second**, depending on the length.

What that means is your iPhone only captured your subject about once per second, so if your subject was walking across the room (for example), they would have traversed about 3 feet in the time it took to capture each frame. All the motion in between is lost.

Unfortunately, iPhone's time lapse mode does not record audio.

**To adjust the speed of a clip, download iMovie for iOS (free):**

1. With your project open, tap the video clip in the timeline to reveal the inspector at the bottom of the screen.
2. Tap the `Speed` button.
3. In the inspector, drag the slider to the left to decrease the speed.

iMovie may not let you slow your footage enough to bring the speed down to normal. You will likely have to save the edited, slowed-down clip and repeat the process again until the speed of the playback appears normal.

Unless there is very little motion in the video, I don't think you will be happy with the result, but no harm in trying. I hope it turns out good enough for your purposes!

Answer (score 0):

Well I see this in from 2017 but going to answer what I have done so far.  I am a stage manager for a play and I record certain things to help the cast.  In the middle of recording my IPAD PRO 2021 had a mind of its own and changed it to slow motion or something.  I was able to change this by importing the video to the editor app INSHOT.  Once in there I was able to save most of the video.  INSHOT has the ability to change the speed.  Now, this is just my first solution.  Looking into why IPAD PRO 2021 just changed the speed.  I have a guess that my IPAD PRO battery was getting low and it slowed everything down, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Slow motion takes more frames per second so you can throw away some frames to speed it up. Time lapse already threw away the content between frames. It wasn’t recorded, so you can’t make it up later.